# Join two JSON files in a same one using java

Tags: java, json, jersey

I Am using Java to write 2 simple REST web services to get from each one a different JSON file:
Here's my code

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/nour")
public class Nour {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)             
    public String sayHelloJSON(){ 
        String Name1 = "Nour Nour";
        int Age1 = 10;
        return "[ \n { \"nm\": \"" + Name1 + "\","
                + " \n\"ag\": " + Age1 + " } \n ]";
    }
}
```

and in my other class, I have this code:

```
public class Stack {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)             
    public String sayHelloJSON(){ 
        String Name2 = "Stack Stack";
        int Age2 = 11;
        return "[ \n { \"nm\": \"" + Name2 + "\","
                + " \n\"ag\": " + Age2 + " } \n ]";
    }
}
```

Whenever I run those two classes in a dynamic project I get two different json files.
My question is:
Can I merge those two json files in a same one using a third class that will show me the following result ? (Is there a sort of calling this classes in an other class to concat their contents?)

```
[
  {
    "nm": "Nour Nour",
    "ag": 10
  },
  {
    "nm": "Stack Stack",
    "ag": 11
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add the following class:

```
class Merger{

        public static String merge(Nour n, Stack s) {
                return "[" + getArrContent(n.sayHelloJSON()) + "," +
                                getArrContent(s.sayHelloJSON()) + "]";
        }
        private static String getArrContent(String str) {
                return str.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        }
}
```

I used the method replace from [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html).

For testing purposes you could do that:

```
class MainClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Merger m = new Merger();
                System.out.println(m.merge(new Nour(), new Stack()));
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It is my pleasure  :)